# Which files did i modify?

Tags: svn

I am wondering, on which projects I actually worked on during the last year. How can I ask SVN, which files I modified. "I" means a certain svn-user in this case, e.g. 'Nras'.

As a bonus on top: How can I see all my commit messages for each of the files I modified?

It would also be fine if this is achieved by a chain of commands, that would not matter to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Run [`svn log <URL> --search USERNAME`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search). Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).
- Use TortoiseSVN's [Revision Log dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html). Read [TortoiseSVN Manual](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html).

Comment: The first command does not give me the files modified by the USERNAME given, it does give me all of his commit messages. That would be the second part of the bonus on top. I am still looking for a way to get a list of all filenames modified by the user. -- Well i guess i can run this command for each project url and at least see on which project i worked on. Or i can even run this for each file url and see my results. So i can not only upvote but even accept this answer. ty!

Comment: @Nras try running `svn log --search --verbose`.